# Several simultaneous AsyncTasks from different Activities - how to catch proper response?

Tags: android

I have several `Activities` and each of them has its own `AsyncTask` which sends requests to a server and catches its responses. These days if `AsyncTask` is in execution I have a `ProgressDialog` which blocks User from navigation to another `Activities`. I want to get rid of the `ProgressDialog` and substitute it with `ProgressBar` view so user can switch between `Activities`. My concern is about the following: what if `AsyncTaskFirst` started in `ActivityFirst` and user navigates to `ActivitySecond` where `AsyncTaskSecond` is starting also, couldn't it happen the `response` from the first request will take ground in `ActivitySecond` so I'll miss it in `ActivityFirst`? If it is impossible, that's fine. If it is - how to handle such a case? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `AsyncTask` begun execution in the first `Activity` then it's execution of the `postExecute` method should be expected to affect the first `Activity` and not the second unless you've explicitly set it up otherwise.

Comment: The AsyncTask doesn't know about the second Activity, and runs in it's own Thread yeah. The postExecute method is called on the Ui Thread, but will be called within the first Activity as that is where the method has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `AsyncTask` has some kind of reference to the `Activity`, so it can update the progress bar.
If this is so, then all you have to do is add a method in the `AsyncTask`:

```
public void setHandler(MyTaskHandler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}
```

When you start a new activity, call this method and pass on the new activity.
Then when the `AsyncTask` calls the `Activity`'s update progress method, it will use the current `Activity` regardless of where the task was started from.

BTW: It might be better to use fragments and not activities, if it's the same component only different parts of the display. Then you do not have this problem at all, because the activity remains the same. See these guides about fragments:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thanks for explanation. My main concern is not how to update the Activity but a possibility to not catch a response from the `AsyncTask` it was sent from.

Comment: Consider fragments instead of activities, it could simplify a lot. You will only have one activity to deal with. In your example, if you move to another activity, the progress bar of the second activity will not be updated. Is that what you want?